# How to force quiet mode from SConstruct

Tags: scons

I know we can force a quiet mode from scons command option by doing the following

```
$ scons -Q
```

Now i would like to be able to forced that option inside the SConstruct file itself. I have been though all the documentation without finding anything. Do you have any clue on how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's option is not supported.

List of supported options that can be set via SetOption(name, value) are:

- clean - which corresponds to -c, --clean and --remove;
- duplicate - which corresponds to --duplicate;
- help - which corresponds to -h and --help;
- implicit_cache - which corresponds to --implicit-cache;
- max_drift - which corresponds to --max-drift;
- no_exec - which corresponds to -n, --no-exec, --just-print, --dry-run
  and --recon;
- num_jobs - which corresponds to -j and --jobs;
- random - which corresponds to --random; and
- stack_size - which corresponds to --stack-size.

So, you can get it but can't set.

```
print GetOption('silent')
SetOption('silent', 1)

scons.bat
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: *** This option is not settable from a SConscript file: silent
File "E:\Programming\test\scons\2\SConstruct", line 1, in <module>
PS E:\Programming\test\scons\2>
PS E:\Programming\test\scons\2> scons.bat
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
False

scons: *** This option is not settable from a SConscript file: silent
File "SConstruct", line 2, in <module>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast, and really detail answer.

Comment: And that sucks, because you can add your own options via `SCons.Script.AddOption`, but you can't set your custom options programatically afterwards...